# Error during MEAN stack installation - phantomjs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, mean

```
C:\Users\Dell\mriob>npm install
npm WARN package.json mean@0.5.5 No license field.
/
> phantomjs@1.9.18 install C:\Users\Dell\mriob\node_modules\phantomjs
> node install.js

Looks like an `npm install -g` on windows; unable to check for already installed version.
Download already available at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantom
js-1.9.8-windows.zip
Extracting zip contents
Error extracting zip
Phantom installation failed Invalid or unsupported zip format. No END header found undefined

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! phantomjs@1.9.18 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs@1.9.18 install script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\mriob\npm-debug.log
```

I tried installing phantomjs using "npm install -g phantomjs". This happens perfectly. But, when I run "npm install" inside the MEAN stack folder "mriob", I get this error.

I tried deleting the phantomjs zip file in temp and then ran "npm install". Same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade your npm version (v2.14.7) to the latest (v3.3.8)

To upgrade npm on Windows

Run PowerShell/CMD as Administrator

execute scripts

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

and run

```
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

Select the last npm version on list (v3.3.8 today)